# Interrupting sequence of numbers in paste ()

Tags: r

I would like to create the following vector:

```
  [1] "x.0" "x.1" "x.3" "x.4"
```

I know that the vector **"x.0" "x.1" "x.2" "x.3" "x.4"** is easily produced by

```
 paste("x", 0:4,sep=".")
```

How to modify this code in order to omit 2 in sequence "0:4"?

May be there is another solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or this to remove any element/s:

```
paste("x", (0:4)[-3], sep=".")
## [1] "x.0" "x.1" "x.3" "x.4"
```

Edit: *(based on comment)*

```
## less ambiguous to include the actual element
paste("x", (0:4)[0:4 != 2], sep=".")
```

Comment: I would prefer `(0:4)[0:4 != 2]` or `(0:4)[!0:4 %in% 2]` if only because of less ambiguity about what number is being removed from the vector.

Comment: (+1) I agree. Edited accordingly.

Comment: +1. I feel this would be easier to read if there were multiple elements to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Just specify the vector of numbers you want to paste as you would normally do with `c()`:

```
> paste("x", c(0, 1, 3:4),sep=".")
[1] "x.0" "x.1" "x.3" "x.4"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's that easy!